# Resolving template block structure conflicts with third-party django apps

Tags: python, django, templates, inheritance, extensibility

When incorporating a third-party django app, I typically want it to be integrated aesthetically with the rest of my django project. While this is typically a matter of overriding the apps 'base.html' (if that), we all structure our templates a little differently, so incompatibilities often arise. For instance, suppose an app defines `{% block footer %}` and and makes use of it for a variety of things throughout its templates. If I am already using `{% block footer %}` for, say, a nav bar or copyright info, I don't want the app's templates to override my block.

A simpler, related case would be using different block names for the same thing. For instance, `{% block extra-head %}` versus `{% block extrahead %}`.

What's the best way of resolving these sorts of situations? Ideally, it would be nice to remap blocks, so you could do things like "put the child's `{% block footer %}` in the parent's `{% block content-footer %}`". Is there any way to get close to that? Or is the only solution to simply override every conflicting template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the html inheritance should go:

```
my-sitebase.html
 |-- app-base.html
   |-- app-foo-template.html
```

I think this is what you meant, but the wording was a bit ambiguous.  You might be able to just edit the app-base.html.

Second, a reusable app that overrides something like {% block footer %} is almost willfully causing trouble for anyone who uses it -- you should flag that in the provider's issue tracker.

If the app does do anything with {% block footer %} that should be done in the app-base.html area so you only have to change it once when integrating it with your site.

Finally, a recursive find-replace is actually very little effort.  If you don't use an IDE that allows this, [Text-Crawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler) is free, lightning fast, and a good non-IDE solution.

There have been a couple of attempts to create a standard inheritance pattern, I put together one that I like for the templates at djangoslingshot.com and I've seen one other -- but so far there hasn't been any coalescence around a standard.  Likely because find-replace is actually a very low cost for the benefit of being able to do exactly what you want without someone else's rules getting in your way.